# PHP calling Python with Base64 image data fails

Tags: php, python

I am trying to make a program for my company, that takes images and sends them to an API with relevant information.

The script takes a title, makes a directory on my system, puts the images in the directory, loops through the directory, converts each image to Base64Data, and passes the data do a python script that posts the data to the API. But for some reason, my loop stops on the first image.

UPDATED CODE: I tried to make the code a little more understandable. I am getting an invalid base64 code from the API. The function "photo" shows the format XML has to be constructed in.

UPDATED - FIX: Used cURL library in PHP instead of passing data to python script.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$count = 0;


function photo($base64, $caption, $description, $displayname, $credits){
    $data = "<image xmlns='http://apiapi.com/cms' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'><caption>'";
    $data .= $caption;
    $data .= "'</caption>";
    $data .= "<credits>'";
    $data .= $credits;
    $data .= "'</credits><data>'";
    $data .= $base64;
    $data .= "'</data>";
    $data .="<description>'";
    $data .= $base64;
    $data .= "'</description><displayname>'";
    $data .= $displayname;
    $data .="'</displayname><extension>JPG</extension>";
    $data .= "<imageusage>SlideShow</imageusage><uploadmethod>Server</uploadmethod>";
    $data .= "</image>";
    return $data; }


function base64url_encode($s) {
    return str_replace(array('+', '/'), array('-', '_'), base64_encode($s));
    }

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $dirty_title = $_POST['title'];
    $title = htmlspecialchars($dirty_title);
    chdir('uploads');
    mkdir($title, 0777, true);
    chdir($title);
    //echo getcwd();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {
       $type = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $superstring = $title . $count .".". $type;
       //echo "SuperString = " . $superstring."<br />";
        if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $superstring)) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }

}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === '' || substr_compare($haystack, $needle, -strlen($needle)) === 0;
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$curdir = getcwd();
//$exiftool = exec('exiftool -all= *.jpg');
//echo "exiftool = ".$exiftool."<br />";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($curdir);
$count = 0;
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo){
   if ($dir == '.' || $dir == '..' || endsWith($fileinfo, ".jpg_original")){}
  else{
      $count ++;
      chmod($fileinfo, 0777);
      $caption = $_POST['caption'];
      $description = $_POST['description'];
      $displayname = $_POST['displayname'];
      $credit = $_POST['credits'];
      $final_info =  $curdir."/".$fileinfo;
      $type = pathinfo($fileinfo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $data = file_get_contents($final_info);
      $mybase = base64url_encode($data);
      echo "Function Worked";
      $photo = photo($mybase, $caption, $description, $displayname, $credit);
      $file_name = "data".$count.".txt";
      $file = fopen($file_name, "w");
      fwrite($file, $photo);
      fclose($file);
      $cwd = getcwd();
      echo "REAL PATH: ".realpath($cwd);



  } 
 }      
  $cwd = getcwd();
  $realpath = realpath($cwd);
  $test =exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/helper_scripts/frankAPI.py '{$realpath}'");
  echo $test;
}
?>
```

And here is the python script that takes the file path as argument, reads the written data that the PHP script wrote, and sends it to the API. Now im getting a 500 error, and its saying the base64 encoding that Im sending isnt recognized as base64.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import requests


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        directory = str(sys.argv[1])

        headers = {'Authorization':'usernameusername',
           'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
        }
        os.chdir(directory)
        dirs = os.listdir('.')

        for file in dirs:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                print file
                with open(file, 'r') as content_file:
                    content = content_file.read()
                    r = requests.post('https://cms.worldnow.com/v1.0/images',
                        headers=headers,
                        data=content)
                    print r.text[0:100]

    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'my loop stops on the first image'? Do you get an error message? Do you get any output (does the python script have output?)? Does it stop before or after the exec?

Comment: i did some debugging. it seems as if exec() works once, then fails to call again.  Here is the output:

I put a "if" check on test. If exec() did run, it would print out the message "test ran". Here is output: Photoname: flower01
Test Ran #######

Photoname: flower02
#######

Photoname: flower03
#######

Comment: Maybe there's a flooding prevention in the python script? Maybe it just fails after the first run? Your PHP looks fine and I'm sure if you replace the exec of the python script with a simple `echo` it would run through. You could try adding a http://at2.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php in your loop... If you could post the python script, it might help to understand the problem.

Comment: updated with python script!

Comment: You probably get the 500 because you are replacing + and / in the base64 string. I guess you are doing this to avoid breaking the XML? You could try putting the unaltered base64 string within CDATA, there special characters would not break the XML.

Comment: This won't help fixing your error and is just a general suggestion for improvement: the python script is rather simple. Why don't you just use a curl POST in PHP to send the XML data to the API? You could greatly reduce possible points of failure.

Comment: My experience with PHP libraries is limited. With python, you simply "Import library" but with PHP cURL library seems to take some extra configuration. I will try and set it up now.

Comment: depending on your OS and how it's set up, php-curl might already be installed.

Comment: I got it with the PHP cURL library!!!